# Android Detect Currently Logged in User

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

There is support for multiple user on `JellyBean` where user can switch between the user by using power button.

Is there any way to detect currently **`logged in or active user`** on device **programatically**.

Comment: Perhaps there is a better Android developer support site -- one in a language in which you are literate -- that can assist you: http://www.andglobe.com.

Answer (score 0):

The current state is to "sign in" with apps. I know this is not exactly what you are asking for but it might lead you to that the question is to be asked differently maybe ? If one agrees that you can "sign in" with apps and different accounts, it's not so important anymore what the active account would  be if something like that exists.

Google promotes the g+ auth method :
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps?hl=de

Or you prompt with a picker which will list those accounts available:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @aldanux , can you tell me how I'm supposed to do that, comment, if *SO* requires me to have 50 reputation. The only thing I'm allowed to do is post answers, nothing else. You can clearly see the *1* next to my name ...

Comment: @CaptainCrunch - I'm not blind and I don't make the rules on SO. But what my eyes see is that make sense the rules.